# Animating list items when moved within array

Tags: angularjs

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RIX34vrFCw1JuOpRh6fB?p=preview)

This plunker shows an array displayed as a list using `ng-repeat`

Each array item has an up and down button allowing it to to change position with the array item above or below.

I'm also using `angular-animate`to flash each item red when it's position is changed.

But what I'd like to do is flash red the item moving up and and flash blue the item moving down.

Any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert at angularJS, but, I do have an idea:

http://jptacek.com/2015/03/angularJS-CSS-Animation/

```
There are five AngularJS events
   enter - DOM element is add to the DOM tree
   leave - DOM element is removed from the DOM tree
   move - DOM element is moved within the DOM tree
   addClass - A class is added to an element
   removeClass - A class is removed from an element
```

So, although "move" is only working on the button you are clicking, you can change your javascript to *add a class* to the other elements that you swap with and move.

Then you can trigger the CSS animation by using something in your css following the

```
[class]-[event]-[state]
```

model, where it can be like

```
.ng-addClass { ... }
.ng-addClass-active { ... }
```